# Can't get OpenGL to work, Games crash on launch, AMD Radeon 6670, Issues with driver?

Tags: drivers, ati, games, steam, opengl

So, I got Ubuntu yesterday, and enthusiastically started to install all my linux supported steam games. Only about two of them worked, and the rest crashed instantly back to steam without error messages, with the exception of Portal, which gives a messages saying it has to deal with OpenGL. I believe this issues is caused by my graphics card drivers. I have a Radeon 6670. What information do I need to give you for you to try and help with getting the appropriate drivers and OpenGL to work?

Comment: Did you install proprietary AMD drivers?

Answer (score -1):

This problem is caused by the Steam's old bundled version of libstdc++.

Possible solutions:

1. (from https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3273) Redirect steam runtime's symlink for libstdc++.so.6 to the systems. Replace XX with the version of your system's libstdc++.
   You need to update this when libstdc++ is updated.

   ```
   $ ln -sf /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.XX ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
   ```
2. (from http://chapeaulinux.org/forums/topic/steam-not-working-in-chapeau-22/) Preload the system's libstdc++ before running steam.

   ```
   $ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 ; steam
   ```

   The last solution can also be put in a script:

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/bin/steam /usr/bin/steam.orig
   echo -e '#!/bin/sh\nexport LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6\n. /usr/bin/steam.orig $*'>~/mysteam
   chmod +x ~/mysteam
   sudo ln -s ~/mysteam /usr/bin/steam
   ```
3. (from search for how-to-fix-broken-steam-linux-client-with-radeon-graphics-driver-workaround/) Create a script to run steam with the system's version of libstdc++.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' #Export so all child    processes are affected as well
   export DISPLAY=:0
   #export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose
   steam
   ```

   Save this as e.g. run-steam.sh. You must start steam through this script.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...